# Loading Properties File in Android

Tags: java, android, file, properties, load

I have a properties file in my android project but I don't know how to read properties from the file. I have seen several tutorials but those did not help me, in addition I am getting some errors. Would you please post some simple example code to understand how this works?

Comment: What format is the properties file?  Why aren't you using the standard Android preferences file?

Comment: Seems like a valid question to me. Lots of java developers use property files in there applications. Nice to use, easy to look at. Great for configurations etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is some example code...

```
Properties props=new Properties();
InputStream inputStream = 
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("example.properties");
props.load(inputStream);
exampleUrl=props.getProperty("baseUrl");
exampleUsername=props.getProperty("username");      
examplepassword=props.getProperty("password");
```

can not help much more without some of your own code. Hope this helps.

Comment: TRAP: this will read the file as ISO-8859-1! If you want to read it as UTF-8, wrap the `InputStream` into an `InputStreamReader` with the correct character set (`Properties` has a `.load()` method accepting to read from a reader)

Comment: Whats the difference if I just want to just get a number from the file and assign it to the variable?

Comment: If you are just getting numbers you should be fine. ISO-8859-1 can represent only the first 256 Unicode characters, the more popularly used ones. UTF-8 can represent all Unicode characters.

Comment: I have a file that has several of these on different lines with different words and numbers "counter=0". I really just want a way to write to this file and read from this file so that it can store numbers needed even after the application is closed.

Comment: If you are only using alphanumeric characters then you should have no problems with my example code.

Comment: Where should I place my properties file inside my project? I just got a chance to add in the code and I get a null pointer exception for the InputStream when i use the properties.load() method.

Comment: well this answer is useless if you do not know where to put your prop file.

Comment: @ZerO The op had a properties file. I answered his request for example code to better understand reading properties. Why are you responding to this a year later? If you don't know where to put your properties folder than ask that question. The method I wrote assumes the properties file is in the same folder as the Class you are calling it from.

Comment: Here there is explained clearly: http://pillsfromtheweb.blogspot.com/2014/09/properties-file-in-android.html